# How to add a button inside every row under a particular column in Bootstrap React Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-bootstrap-table

I have a React Bootstrap table(http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/index.html) which will get populated from data coming in from an API. I want to add a button to one of the columns and then perform operations on it.
For example, once the button is clicked in a particular row, I need to extract data from the particular row and then make an API call. 
How to the above using React Bootstrap table?

```
    return (
  <BootstrapTable
    condensed={true}
    data = { tableData } 
  //I use tableData to store information obtained from API

    headerStyle={ { 
      background: '#FFF',
    } }
    containerStyle={ { background: '#FFF' } }
    ref='table'
    >
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='resourceId' isKey dataAlign='center' dataSort={ true }> ID </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='Name' dataAlign='center'> Name </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='support' dataAlign='center' dataSort={ true }> Support</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='status' dataAlign='center' dataSort={ true }> Status</TableHeaderColumn>


      <TableHeaderColumn 
        dataAlign='center'
        options={ 
      <button> Select </button>}
      >
      File Path
      </TableHeaderColumn>
//Insert button here and access onClick property and make relevant API calls

  </BootstrapTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom dataformatter:

```
class ActionFormatter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click me!</button>
    );
  }
}

function actionFormatter(cell, row) {
  return (
    <ActionFormatter onClick={()=>doAction(row)} />
  );
}
```

And in the column:

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='action' dataFormat={ actionFormatter }>Action</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select you columns either by class or you can use a query selector

```
var column = document.querySelectorAll("tableHeaderColumn");
```

Loop through them adding the button to each. Edit properties of button as you see fit.

```
for(var i = 0; i < column.length; i++){
 column[i].innerHTML += "<button></button>";
}
```