# How to make a column as clickable in a react bootstrap table and avoid showing it as text field in "Add Row"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I referred to the following to make a column in my react bootstrap table clickable:

[How to add a button inside every row under a particular column in Bootstrap React Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464713/how-to-add-a-button-inside-every-row-under-a-particular-column-in-bootstrap-reac)

But when i using the "Add New Row" button, the column in my react bootstrap table is still a text field. I want that column to be a button/clickable url there as well.

Kindly, help me with this.

A part of my code is:

```
class ButtonFormatter extends Component {
    render(){
    return (
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick }> Additional Info </button>
    );
    }
}

function buttonFormatter(cell, row) {
    return (
        <ButtonFormatter />
    );
}

<BootstrapTable deleteRow={true} selectRow={selectRowProp} options={options} 
   insertRow={ true } data={this.props.data} cellEdit={cellEditProp}>

<TableHeaderColumn width='175' dataField="additionalinformation" dataFormat={ 
   buttonFormatter }> Additional Info </TableHeaderColumn>

</BootstrapTable>
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to show the code that you have tried before posting here for help. Checkout the [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Dvorog I added  my code. Can you please help me in resolving it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing an onClick prop to the ButtonFormatter. You need a method to handle the onClick event and then you need to pass that method to the ButtonFormatter. Something along the lines of this:

```
function handleClick() {
   // code to add row
}

function buttonFormatter(cell, row) {
    return (
        <ButtonFormatter onClick={() => handleClick()} />
    );
}
```